# Appcelerator - iOS - KrollObject forgetKeylessKrollObject

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Recently we have received a crash on one of our application with the following stack trace:

```
0     libobjc.A.dylib                       0x00000001806c1bd0 objc_msgSend + 12
1     CoreFoundation                        0x0000000180f72d90 -[NSInvocation retainArguments] + 208
2     Foundation                            0x00000001819e86b4 -[NSInvocationOperation initWithInvocation:] + 72
3     Foundation                            0x00000001819e85c8 -[NSInvocationOperation initWithTarget:selector:object:] + 216
4     MyApp                                 0x0000000100054500 -[KrollObject forgetKeylessKrollObject:] (KrollObject.m:1079)
5     MyApp                                 0x00000001000a1cac -[TiProxy forgetProxy:] (TiProxy.m:725)
6     MyApp                                 0x000000010005b070 -[TiViewProxy remove:] (TiViewProxy.m:261)
7     MyApp                                 0x00000001000ba294 __TiThreadPerformOnMainThread_block_invoke (TiBase.m:270)
8     MyApp                                 0x00000001000ba570 TiThreadProcessPendingMainThreadBlocks (TiBase.m:367)
9     libdispatch.dylib                     0x0000000180a95630 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
10   libdispatch.dylib                      0x0000000180a955f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
11   libdispatch.dylib                      0x0000000180a9acf8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1840
12   CoreFoundation                         0x0000000180ff8bb0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
13   CoreFoundation                         0x0000000180ff6a18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1624
14   CoreFoundation                         0x0000000180f25680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 380
15   GraphicsServices                       0x0000000182434088 GSEventRunModal + 176
16   UIKit                                  0x0000000185d9cd90 UIApplicationMain + 200
17   MyApp                                  0x000000010003c584 main (main.m:37)
```

Dashboard suggests that the crash has happened at forgetKeylessKrollObjject method. From the stack trace it seems that during a view removal, this indicent happened. There are many places in the code where we have added and removed view. As there is no definite place defined in the log and nor we have the test case, we went through the framework code and saw that there is no null handling inside the method as TiProxy.m --> krollObjectForBridge function can return nil.

If anyone from the community has received such report and been able to resolve it. Please do let us know as there is no way to map this stack trace back to the JavaScript code.

SDK: 3.5.0.GA

OS: iOS 9.1

Comment: urns out, I read your question wrong and thought it was a compile issue. Crashlogs are almost impossible to use with Titanium I'm afraid

Comment: I thought so that you might have read it wrong, but that is OK. . The only information that we can obtain is application called something like TiUIView.remove, but then it caused the crash.

Comment: In-case anyone is interested in the community here is the link 

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20296